# Apache processes stuck in "write" state

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

My apache server is producing lots of processes in "write" state until 
 all slots are filled and the whole webserver hangs. Here's what I got:

```
root@viking:/# uname -a
Linux viking 2.6.32-51-server #113-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 21 20:01:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@viking:/# apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
```

Here's a stack of hanged process:

```
root@viking:/# cat /proc/14475/stack
[<ffffffff81158c39>] poll_schedule_timeout+0x39/0x60
[<ffffffff81158e93>] do_poll+0x233/0x2c0
[<ffffffff81159965>] do_sys_poll+0x155/0x210
[<ffffffff81159c1c>] sys_poll+0x7c/0x110
[<ffffffff81013172>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

This is hot it appears in server-status:

```
Srv PID Acc M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-0 14472   0/1033/1033 W   8.65    965 0   0.0 8.43    8.43    178.129.218.193 ***.com GET /programs/ HTTP/1.0
```

What may cause such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

One common cause of this behavior is malicious clients. They connect to your web server, request some data, and then never read the data your server sends them. This eats up your connection slots.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that it were hanged curl requests to unavailable service. For some reason curl never times out and waits for response forever.